# Guess a number game stops after getting input from player

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

I made this simple guess a number game but when i try it, code ends after getting input from player.

Code:

```
class Gra():

    def __init__(self, minimum, maximum, dobra_liczba):
        self.minimum = minimum
        self.maximum = maximum
        self.dobra_liczba = dobra_liczba

    def sprawdz_liczbe_int(self, liczba):
        print("sprawdzam liczbe")
        if isinstance(liczba, int) and self.minimum <= liczba <= self.maximum:
            return True
    else:
        return False

    def czy_liczba_trafiona(self, liczba):
        if liczba == self.dobra_liczba:
            print("trafiłeś!")
        else:
            print("pudło!")

    def graj(self):
        x = int(input("wpisz liczbe od "+str(self.minimum)+" do "+str(self.maximum)+": "))
        print(x)
        if self.sprawdz_liczbe_int(x) == True:
        self.czy_liczba_trafiona(x)

a1 = Gra(0, 100, 50)
a1.graj()
```

i tried running this code and it didn't work, but when i tried on online compilers code worked.

Comment: "code ends after getting input from player" - why is this a problem? What did you expect? Also, what exactly do you mean by "it didn't work"? _How_ did it "not work"?

Comment: after getting input from player it should check and print if its correct or wrong, but that doesn't happen

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that you want the player to **remain** playing until he gets a hit. In that case, you need to loop over the method that calls the player to enter a guess, which in your case is the `graj(self)` method. Also, if your method is to return a Boolean, like the one in `sprawdz_liczbe_int(self, liczba)`, then you don't need an "if" statement, as returning the statement itself is sufficient.

```
class Gra():

    def __init__(self, minimum, maximum, dobra_liczba):
        self.minimum = minimum
        self.maximum = maximum
        self.dobra_liczba = dobra_liczba

    def sprawdz_liczbe_int(self, liczba):
        print("sprawdzam liczbe")
        return isinstance(liczba, int) and self.minimum <= liczba <= self.maximum  # Immediately return the result of the statement whether it's True or False

    def czy_liczba_trafiona(self, liczba):
        if liczba == self.dobra_liczba:
            print("trafiłeś!")
        else:
            print("pudło!")
            self.graj()  # Loop over the input method

    def graj(self):
        x = int(input("wpisz liczbe od "+str(self.minimum)+" do "+str(self.maximum)+": "))
        print(x)
        if self.sprawdz_liczbe_int(x):  # Basically saying: "If True:"
            self.czy_liczba_trafiona(x)


a1 = Gra(0, 100, 50)
a1.graj()
```

Comment: https://youtu.be/YS8t6LnaWNM you can see here whats happening to my code.

Comment: i made change and code works when opening file but doesn't work on sublime text

Comment: @kiciarozek I think the problem is with sublime text itself, watch this: http://y2u.be/2DKArbsBdgs